# Syncing two files when one is still being written to

Tags: linux, shell, synchronization, streaming, rsync

I have an application (video stream capture) which constantly writes its data to a single file. Application typically runs for several hours, creating ~1 gigabyte file. Soon (in a matter of several seconds) after it quits, I'd like to have 2 copies of file it was writing - let's say, one in `/mnt/disk1`, another in `/mnt/disk2` (the latter is an USB flash drive with FAT32 filesystem).

I don't really like an idea of modifying the application to write 2 copies simulatenously, so I though of:

- Application starts and begins to write the file (let's call it `/mnt/disk1/file.mkv`)
- Some utility starts, copies what's already there in `/mnt/disk1/file.mkv` to `/mnt/disk2/file.mkv`
- After getting initial sync state, it continues to follow a written file in a manner like `tail -f` does, copying everything it gets from `/mnt/disk1/file.mkv` to `/mnt/disk2/file.mkv`
- Several hours pass
- Application quits, we stop our syncing utility
- Afterwards, we run a quick `rsync /mnt/disk1/file.mkv /mnt/disk2/file.mkv` just to make sure they're the same. In case if they're the same, it should just run a quick check and quit fairly soon.

What is the best approach for syncing 2 files, preferably using simple Linux shell-available utilities? May be I could use some clever trick with FUSE / md device / `tee` / `tail -f`?

### Solution

The best possible solution for my case seems to be

```
mencoder ... -o >(
   tee /mnt/disk1/file.mkv |
   tee /mnt/disk2/file.mkv |
   mplayer -
)
```

This one uses bash/zsh-specific magic named "process substitution" thus eliminating the need to make named pipes manually using `mkfifo`, and displays what's being encoded, as a bonus :)

Comment: rsync isn't magic.  To make sure two files are the same, it still has to read every byte.  It saves huge amounts of time over networks by using checksums.  On a single host, the bandwidth to the disk is the cap, and it sadly can't do anything to improve that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmmm... the file is not usable while it's being written, so why don't you "trick" your program into writing through a pipe/fifo and use a 2nd, very simple program, to create 2 copies?

This way, you have your two copies as soon as the original process ends.

Comment: Hmm... Something like `mkfifo some-pipe; tee /mnt/disk1/file.mkv >/mnt/disk2/file.mkv <some-pipe; application >some-pipe; killall tee` ? It might work... Where's the catch here? Any potential problems?

Comment: @GreyCat: `tee` takes its input from its stdin not from a file passed as an argument (which would be an output file).

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: Yes, that's why stdin is being redirected with `<some-pipe`.

Comment: @GreyCat: That should work - and you won't have to kill `tee` either, it will exit when the pipe is closed by the application.  The only problem will be if the application tries to seek on the file it is writing.

Answer (score -1):

Read the manual page on `tee(1)`.